# How To Remove $ Character From All Rows (Which Contains The $) in a Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table called `Products` and column called `Price` in some of rows I have `$` with numbers and I need to update the table to only keeps the numbers in `Price` and removes the `$`. For Example

```
$230.00  -> 230
```

Can you please let me know how to do this through SQL

Comment: What have you tried so far? String replacement should be a fairly easy function to search for in the documentation.

Comment: The deeper problem here is that you are storing price data as a string... don't do that. Use a numeric data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE `Products`
SET `Price` = REPLACE(`Price`, '$', '')
WHERE `Price` LIKE '%$%';
```

This won't remove the cents / decimal places like in your example but are you sure you want to do that?